# Significato di "in più" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *L’amore ai tempi del Covid-19*<sup>1</sup>, di Antonio Manzini,  ho letto (grassetto mio):

> «No, voglio capire perché uno a trent'anni sta a casa della sorella». 
>       Pietro si guardò le mani. «Perché casa dei miei genitori l’abbiamo venduta». 
>       «Ah, altrimenti starebbe con loro?». 
>       «Con chi? Con quei due vecchi rincoglioniti? Ma per carità!». 
>       Rocco si grattò la barba. «Sì, ma sempre con quei vecchi rincoglioniti sta vivendo, no? **In più** su un divano letto».

Questo Pietro e i suoi genitori abitano a casa della sorella, di cui precedentemente si è detto questo:

> La casa era di 90 metri quadrati. In fondo al corridoio la stanza dei bambini, accanto quella matrimoniale, nel saloncino con l'angolo cottura si apriva un piccolo balcone che fungeva anche da sgabuzzino. La stanza da letto accanto all'ingresso era aperta. Due anziani, seduti sul materasso con indosso la mascherina, si tenevano le mani e pareva tremassero. 
>       La moglie e i figli erano in salone seduti sul divano a due posti.

Leggendo questo passaggio, la mia impressione è che i genitori (questi "due anziani") dormissero in questa "stanza da letto accanto all’ingresso", mentre invece Pietro lo facesse su questo "divano a due posti".

La mia domanda è sul significato di questo "in più" che appare nel primo brano. Potrebbe voler dire "per di più", cioè, "per giunta", "inoltre"? Alla [voce "più" del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/piu), ho trovato parecchi usi della locuzione "in più", ma nessuno con questo significato.

---

<sup>1. Secondo il [blog di Licia Corbolante](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2020/02/12/nome-malattia-coronavirus-2019-ncov/), che si occupa di ricerca terminologica e qualità linguistica, 
dovrebbe essere "della COVID-19", ma in questo racconto l'autore fa confusione tra virus e malattia.</sup>

Comment: La tua supposizione è corretta. Espressione equivalente a "per di più", "in aggiunta", "inoltre", "come se non bastasse", "per soprammercato".

Comment: Riguardo la nota: perché credi che "la COVID-19" sia corretto? Ho sempre sentito la parola al maschile. È vero che molte malattie sono femminili, ma non tutte: il vaiolo, il tetano, il cancro, lo scorbuto...

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Si veda, per esempio, http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2020/02/12/nome-malattia-coronavirus-2019-ncov/. Infatti, in questo racconto, Manzini chiama Covid-19 al virus, ma il nome del virus è SARS-CoV-2.

Comment: Io, per il niente che conta, uso “Covid-19” al femminile (pensando a “malattia”, in quanto la “d” sta per _disease_). In Francia, dove sono più prescrittivi, s'è espressa in proposito l'Académie française: http://academie-francaise.fr/le-covid-19-ou-la-covid-19

Comment: Per quanto riguarda allo spagnolo, si è posta la [domanda su Spanish.SE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/34413/).

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Potresti convertire il tuo commento in una risposta, per favore?

Comment: Posso capire le vostre preferenze personali, ma *Dovrebbe essere "della COVID-19"* implica che "il Covid-19" sia scorretto, cosa su cui non sono proprio d'accordo perché su questi termini stranieri è l'uso che si consolida quello che conta. O dite anche *la party* perché vuol dire *festa*?

Comment: Forse dovrei dire "dovrebbe essere del SARS-CoV-2" perché nel racconto Manzini si riferisce sempre al virus. Per esempio: "L’infezione partì in sordina ma quel bastardo di Covid-19, questo era il nome scientifico del virus, si trasmetteva con uno starnuto, una stretta di mano, un respiro".

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Siamo d'accordo che è l'uso che fa testo, ma da cosa ricavi che in questo caso l'uso prediliga il maschile? Facendo un grossolanissimo confronto fra "il covid" e "la covid" con Google, il femminile prevale per circa 57 milioni a 17 milioni.

Comment: @DaG La maggior parte di quei risultati per "la covid" vengono da francese e spagnolo. Se restringi la ricerca ai soli siti .it, il maschile vince 15 milioni contro meno di 1 milione.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Ammetto che ho guardato solo le prime pagine, in cui "la covid" è usato (in italiano) dal Ministero della salute, da altri enti, dalla Wikipedia, da vari quotidiani e agenzie di stampa (occhio che molti siti in italiano non sono .it, ma .com, .eu etc.). Comunque, ognuno dica come vuole, e speriamo che presto non ne parli più nessuno.

Comment: @DaG Dopo questa nostra discussione è arrivato anche un [articolo](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/il-covid19-o-la-covid19/2787) dell'Accademia della Crusca sul tema il/la Covid.

Comment: Ah, grazie per la segnalazione, @FedericoPoloni!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Charo la tua supposizione è corretta, questa espressione significa, appunto come hai scritto, *"per giunta"* oppure *"inoltre"*.

Espressioni con significato analogo e di utilizzo comune sono (l'elenco non è esaustivo):  *"per di più", "in aggiunta", "come se non bastasse" e "per soprammercato"*.