# Significato di "farsi la rota"

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *L’amore ai tempi del Covid-19*<sup>1</sup>, di Antonio Manzini,  ho letto (grassetto mio):

> «Coca. Quanta ne tiri al giorno?».
>    
>       
>   «Io? Io non tiro la coca!». 
>   
>       
>   «Ah no?». 
>   
>       
>   «No!». 
>   
>       
>   Rocco sorrise. «Sei nei guai?». 
>   
>       
>   Pietro si alzò dalla poltrona. «E con chi? Perché? Lei si sta proiettando un film tutto suo». 
>   
>       
>   «No, io osservo. E guardo. Ti tremano le mani, hai le gengive distrutte, salivazione azzerata. Vuoi farmi sentire l’alito o ti arrendi e mi dici la verità?». 
>   
>       
>   Pietro abbassò la testa. «Ogni tanto, alle feste, con qualche amico...». 
>   
>       
>   «Per ridurti così altro che ogni tanto. Te la curi la xerostomia?». 
>   
>       
>   Si passò la mano nei capelli. «No, ma adesso smetto. Infatti sto approfittando di questa chiusura, **mi faccio la rota**».

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "farsi la rota" che appare in questo passaggio. Me lo potreste spiegare? Si tratta di qualche espressione colloquiale?

Ho cercato alla voce "rota" di parecchi dizionari, ma le accezioni che ho trovato non sembrano avere senso in questo contesto.

---

<sup>1. Secondo il [blog di Licia Corbolante](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2020/02/12/nome-malattia-coronavirus-2019-ncov/), che si occupa di ricerca terminologica e qualità linguistica, 
dovrebbe essere "della COVID-19", ma in questo racconto l'autore fa confusione tra virus e malattia.</sup>

Comment: La storia si svolge a Roma? In questo forum https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/sto-a-rota.1333544/ ho trovato l'espressione "essere/stare a rota" nel senso di essere in crisi di astinenza da una droga. Espressione probabilmente derivata dalla tortura medievale della ruota.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi:  Come si spiega [qui](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocco_Schiavone), si svolge ad Aosta. Ma Manzini è romano.

Comment: Nello stesso forum di prima, viene detto che l'espressione è di uso comune per i tossicodipendenti indipendentemente dalla regione (anche se a me, personalmente, "rota" fa proprio pensare a delle origini romanesche del detto). In sostanza  "mi faccio la rota" significa "tento di smettere (di drogarmi)", il che per un tossicodipendente equivale a una tortura - l'espressione è più colorita e dà l'idea di qualcosa che si fa molto ma molto di controvoglia.

Comment: Da romano, confermo che quello che viene subito in mente è una variante sulla locuzione “stare a rota”.

Comment: @DaG: "Stare a rota" col senso di essere in astinenza dalle droghe, come si spiega in [questo blog](https://federicaaceto.wordpress.com/2015/01/16/litaliano-regionale-nelle-traduzioni/)?

Comment: La nota al piede mi sembra inutile. Può benissimo essere *il covid-19*, prendendo il genere da *morbo*. Per esempio, AIDS è usato senza problemi al maschile. Non c'è alcuna confusione tra virus e morbo/malattia. E, di fatto, si legge *il covid-19* dappertutto.

Comment: @egreg: A dire il vero, forse nella nota dovrei scrivere "dovrebbe essere del SARS-CoV-2" perché nel racconto Manzini si riferisce sempre al virus. Per esempio: "L’infezione partì in sordina ma quel bastardo di Covid-19, questo era il nome scientifico del virus, si trasmetteva con uno starnuto, una stretta di mano, un respiro". A quanto pare, [non dappertutto](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/12938/significato-di-in-pi%c3%b9-in-questo-contesto#comment30659_12938).

Comment: Esattamente, @Charo.